# why is begin() needed in std::vector erase?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Why do we have to write `v.erase(v.begin(), v.begin()+3)` ?

Why isn't it defined as `erase(int, int)` so you can write `v.erase(0,2)` and the implementation takes care of the `begin()`s?

Comment: because whole stl works with iterators, and it is convinient , and because if you will want later change vector to list, you would not need to change code, if you use iterators, no such luck with int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interface `container.erase(iterator, iterator)` is more general and works for containers that don't have indexing, like `std::list`. This is an advantage if you write templates and don't really know exactly which container the code is to work on.

The original design aimed at being as general as possible, and iterators are more general than indexes. The designers *could* have added extra index-based overloads for `vector`, but decided not to.

Comment: Furthermore, the iterators may come from `<algorithm>` functions, and having _those_ return indexes would be extremely constrictive.

Answer (score 1):

In STL, iterators are the only entity that provides general access to STL containers.

The array data structure can be accessed via pointers and indexes. iterators are generalization of these indexes/pointers.
Linked list can be accessed with moving pointers (a la `ptr = ptr->next`). iterators are generalization to these.
Trees and HashTables need special iterator class which encapsulates the logic of iterating these data structures.

As you can see, iterators are the general type which allows you to do common operations (such as iteration, deletion etc.) on data structures, regardless their underlying implementation.

This way, you can refactor your code to use `std::list` and `container.erase(it0, it1)` still works without modifying the code.